# Unable to delete Kernel malware in extension which hampers my all connections including wifi. Wi-Fi shows no hardware installed

Tags: wifi, mojave, malware

I had downloaded an Ethernet adapter driver from Mac which disabled my wifi. My wifi icon shows no hardware installed. Malware is located in `/System/Library/Extensions`. It is a kernel extension named "Apple Realtek" and I am unable to uninstall it. Whenever I try to drag it to trash it says your Mac requires this file and I cannot even change it to read and write after unlocking it. My wifi, Bluetooth and other connections are not working.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you tried running an anti-malware product like Malwarebytes?

Comment: Reinstall Mojave from macOS Recovery following this [guide from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). You might want to check [this Q&A here at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214995/how-to-use-3rd-party-usb-ethernet-adapter-with-el-capitan) concerning Realtek ethernet adaptors.

Comment: What do you mean by "I had downloaded Ethernet adapter driver from mac." That makes no sense. "mac" is a nickname for a line of computers made by Apple. So where **exactly** did you download this driver from? What is the make and model of this ethernet adapter? We will need you to edit your question to answer these questions. Without that we are unlikely to be able to assist you.

Comment: @SteveChambers: sounds like OP downloaded something from a rogue site/dialog box/app claiming to be Apple.

Comment: @smci, my thought exactly. It *SOUNDS* like a malware download, but with no response from the OP, no way to assist...