# Mojave + USB ethernet adapter. kext wrong headers? Lib declarations?

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extensions

Following [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214995/how-to-use-3rd-party-usb-ethernet-adapter-with-el-capitan) question it should be possible to install a .kext for either of my USB adapters. 
However, after disabling SPI and fixing file permissions in the kext directory, kextload fails and kextutil informs me that the various drivers are all built against the wrong headers. But I'm running Majave 10.4 and the driver from ASIX is listed as compatible on the download page. I've tried the other kext linked in the question above too.

Notably, I also can't use the pkg installer for the ASIX driver.

```
MacBook-Pro:Downloads user$ sudo kextutil AX88179_178A.kext
Disabling KextAudit: SIP is off
(kernel) kxld[com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a]: The super class vtable '__ZTV20IOEthernetController' for vtable '__ZTV7AX88179' is out of date. Make sure your kext has been built against the correct headers.
(kernel) Can't load kext com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a - link failed.
(kernel) Failed to load executable for kext com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a.
(kernel) Kext com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a failed to load (0xdc008016).
(kernel) Failed to load kext com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a (error 0xdc008016).
Failed to load /Users/user/Downloads/AX88179_178A.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Check library declarations for your kext with kextlibs(8).
```

[image: dialog box of package installer]

[image: USB devices]

edit: 
**I believe that the driver just isn't compatible with Mojave but I'd really like someone to confirm this for me please. I think the dev made the mistake of selecting the o/s version XX.XX and above but didn't actually use the older version of Xcode to build it.**

Comment: Just going to add some info I found on a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011502/iopcidevice-not-linked-when-loading-kext https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48775

Comment: ...a mismatch between the SDK version you are building against and the OS X version you are trying to load your kext on.Unlike OS X userspace, setting the "Deployment Target" to the minimum OS X version supported by your driver is not sufficient.must also use the OS X SDK version matching the oldest supported OS X version for this very reason of reserved virtual functions.
e.g. maybe you're building with the 10.10 or 10.11 SDK,but are trying to load the kext on 10.9. That won't work. Use Xcode 6.3.2 (the newest version that ships with the 10.9 SDK), select the 10.9 SDK, and build with that."